# Intellij can't find .js files (class search)

Tags: javascript, search, intellij-idea

I use intellij for developing, but mostly with Java. Recently I cloned a project with only javascript files, and when I try to search for classes intellij can't find them. It's a big project, so it's important to get the search to work. I have never experienced this with java files before. Does anyone have a fix for this? It finds them if I use 'search everywhere', but not with the class search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript don't have Java classes. Search for files instead.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

`Go to class: Ctrl + N`

`Go to file: Ctrl + Shift + N`

Comment: I wasn't aware of the 'go to file' shortcut :) Thank you!